# Eclipse plugin start error NoClassDefFoundError for SWT class

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, equinox

When launching Ecipse IDE product with a plugin in development I got the following error:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2018-10-19 10:42:34.466 !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception !STACK 0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/graphics/Rectangle   at swing2swt.layout.BorderLayout.layout(BorderLayout.java:100)  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1386)

I'm on Windows and telling from the Installation Details dialog of the launched applicatiion, the required plugin is present. It exports that missing package. In my plugin I'm importing that package. I don't know where else I can check. Please help!

P.S. This run configuration was working before. But then I had to switch from the PC I was using to a VM. I opened the workspace and used Eclipse quick fix to clear some of the warnings. But I cleared a lot and don't know which one is causing the issue. I've reverted a lot of the changes but it's still not working.

Comment: Show us your plugin's MANIFEST.MF

Comment: I managed to make it work (again). The build.properties needed to list bin/ in its binary build inclusions. The reason why the warning quick fix removed it, or why it is made removable at all is beyond me.